# Springboot+webflux+Websocket how to handle session timeout in serverside

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

Need related about for the springboot +webflux+Websocket.
How to handle the session timeout in the server side based on the each socket connection, when websocket connection alive in Client side, can we do session timeout handling in websocket server side ?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-websocket.html